# Software to A) merge two faces into one and B) morph one into another for Mac?

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, photos, image-editing, graphics

I'm looking for a program (or programs) that will allow me to do two things:

1. Create a video of one photo of a face morphing into another photo of a face.  (This requires tagging the matched elements somehow, I presume.
2. Allow me to create a merged image from two faces, sort of like a "what if they had a baby" kind of thing.  Note that Morph Thing, which does this online, won't work for me, as it won't work with decent size images.

A paid Mac app would be fine, as would multiple apps, if there's not one that does both of the above.

The only ones I've found online all seemed to be on random download sites that lacked credibility.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A quick search gave me two promising applications:

- Commercial: [Creaceed Morph Age](http://www.creaceed.com/morphage/)
- Freeware: [Norrkross MorphX](http://www.norrkross.com/software/morphx/)

I believe that both do what you want.

Comment: thanks- MorphX did the trick.  I'd found it in my initial search, but written it off, as it seemed to render gibberish, but I tried again, and figured out that if you set the window size too big, the app can't handle the graphics in real time, but in smaller size, it works perfectly...

Comment: Great! Glad to hear it worked for you.